# Getting an asset Url from an entry loop into a meta tag

Tags: templating

I found it pretty straightforward to get something like dynamic page titles working by setting a variable at the template level and pulling that into my site's meta tags:

My _layout.twig:

```
<head>
{% if title is defined %}
<title>{{ title }}</title>
{% endif %}
</head>
```

My template.twig:

```
{% set title = entry.title %}
```

But what's the best practice for pulling something like an asset URL that needs queried from within {% block content %}? I'm running a for loop on my asset field to grab the Url from within the template, but this doesn't seem to work outside of `{% block content %}`, and if I run it from within `{% block content %}` the variable doesn't carry over to _layout.twig where I need it in the meta tag.

My _layout.twig looks like this:

```
{% if openGraphImage is defined %}
<meta property="og:image" content="{{openGraphImage}}" />
{% endif %}
```

But how can I define an image Url that's coming from within an entry query and have it pass back to the meta tag?

Comment: Hey, can you share the code you've tried for setting the image Url?

Comment: @dmatthams Thanks for your comment! I was trying to set a variable (and pass it into my _layout.twig file outside of a {% block %} tag. Doing so fixed it and I added the working code I'm now using as an answer below.

Comment: Glad you sorted it :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have a full understanding of how blocks work, but I've solved my problem. I think because I was trying to set the variable in my template *outside of the block* (and I was trying to bring it into my _layout.twig file without referencing the block I was calling) nothing was getting properly passed from one file to the other. The solution I'm now using looks like this:

_layout.twig:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{% block ogImage %}{% endblock %}" />
```

template.twig:

```
{% block ogImage %}
    {% for image in entry.eventImage.all() %}
        {{ image.url() }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```